# Need help in VB.NET list / notepad

Tags: vb.net, file, io

I have a problem with VB.NET and I need some help...
I have a notepad which contains duplicates of each line, for example : http://pastebin.com/6Qm33ktv .

I want to create an application which removes 2 of "Line one (Duplicated 3 times)" and keeps 1, basically removes the duplicated lines...

Comment: As it is, this question is impossible to answer... Where are these rows being stored? What controls are being used to store/display them? What actually is going on in your application?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/rgpxpG60
Button 1 browses for the notepad location
Button 2 removes duplicates
Button 3 saves updated list without duplicates to notepad

Comment: Where is it getting the data from, though?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/JvzTfnQd Here "C:\Users\slammyslam23\Desktop\info.txt" and it adds all lines from notepad to list in VB.NET now how do I remove the duplicates and update the notepad?

Answer (score 0):

Answering this 2-days old question, I happened to do this a few years ago in an attempt to get item names from a file and check for duplicates

I won't be discussing the File I/O part, so once you get the string array for the file contents (Hint: `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines`), iterate through that and check the List before inserting the line:

```
'Let's say that our file consists of these 4 elements:
Dim fileCont as String() = {"123","345","123","124" }
Dim strList as New List(Of String)

For i = 0 To fileCont.Length - 1
    If Not strList.Contains(fileCont(i)) Then
        strList.Add(fileCont(i))
    End If
Next
'The list now has 3 elements.
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and I'm sorry for letting you waste your time, it seems that Notepad++ contains a plug-in called TextFX which does this automatically for you, also possible to check for case sensitive/insensitive lines/letters, thanks for the answer once again!